# Lusztig's completion for universal enveloping algebra

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

In Arkhipov, Bezrukavnikov and Ginzburg's paper "[Quantum Groups, the loop Grassmannian and the Springer resolution](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2004-17-03/S0894-0347-04-00454-0/S0894-0347-04-00454-0.pdf)", they mentioned that Lusztig introduced a certain completion for universal enveloping algebra $\widehat{U\mathfrak{g}}$, so that the finite dimensional representions $Rep(\widehat{U\mathfrak{g}})$ is isomorphic to $Rep(G)$, where $G$ is the connected semisimple group of adjoint type with lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

What is the construction of this completion? Any references?

Comment: Are you assuming that the ground field has characteristic zero? is algebraically closed? are you assuming that $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple?

Comment: @YCor I have edited as the setting in their paper. Though I am curious whether such construction exists for general field or not.

Comment: in which page of the cited article where is this mentioned ?

Comment: Section 2.6 Frobenius functor

Comment: If $(V_n)$ is the list of finite-dim irreducibles that integrate to $G$, it's tempting to take this completion as the product of matrix algebras $\prod_nEnd(V_n)$. We just need it to only have the $V_n$ as finite-dim irreducibles. This can be forced by endowing the product with the product topology (say the field is discrete, so $End(V_n)$ is discrete). But I guess that in this setting it's unnecessary, in the sense that every finite-dim rep of $\prod_nEnd(V_n)$ factors through $\prod_{k\le n}End(V_k)$ for some $n$.